# How `this.props` is defined and information is saved into global Redux state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am new to react and Redux and utilize a react project on GitHub: [overcode/rovercode-ui](https://github.com/rovercode/rovercode-ui) to learn react and Redux. I have some questions about it.

1. For each component in fold `component`, I cannot find why the component has so many props. For example, for `Workspace` component, at the end of file `\component\Workspace`, it checks the props of `Workspace` component. **I wonder where these props come from (namely where these props are defined), e.g., the `code` props.**
2. Action `createProgram` defined in file `\actions\code.js` use an asynchronous `POST` method to create an `id` for newly created program. However, in the sub-reducer `\reducers\code.js`, when `action.type` equals to `CREATE_PROGRAM_FULFILLED`, `id` will be extracted from `action.payload` to save into global state. So, **how the `id` is saved into the global state and action of type `CREATE_PROGRAM_FULFILLED` is dispatched?**

Can anyone help me analze this project? Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Instead of trying to analyze a project that's over your head, consider checking out the redux and react-redux docs and writing your own app from scratch first. Without knowing what `mapStateToProps` does you're not going to get very far.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I have learnt part of concept but still have these puzzles. I will continue to learn :)

Answer (score 0):

Hello and welcome to React - Redux universe. I am sure you will love it but regardless of your background or experience level, you have to make your peace with the fact that there is a learning curve and when you are especially new to thinking in terms of components, developing a different mindset takes time. Don't worry, we all been there and it will past. Just give yourself some time.

I am afraid, even if we spend some time together to analyze this project, I don't think that it would make your life easier in terms or learning React or Redux. Analyzing this project is more like helping a beginner foreign language learner to translate a story. It might help you to understand the story, but at the end you won't probably be able to write a new story in the language you are trying to learn.

That said, I'll try to briefly provide answers to your questions and try to point out why analyzing this specific project will not be as helpful as you would expect

1) In order to comprehend where all these props come from, you need to recognize the following pattern that is

```
connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Workspace))
```

so basically, thanks to `connect`function, you can connect your component directly to the redux store (you name it as global state)

For instance, let's take a look at the following snipped from the file https://github.com/rovercode/rovercode-ui/blob/alpha/src/components/Workspace.js#L36

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, { cookies }) => ({
  updateJsCode: jsCode => dispatch(actionUpdateJsCode(jsCode)),
```

Basically, thanks to `mapDispatchToProps` we return an object. And since we use mapDispatchToProps as a parameter of `connect` function, `connect` function takes the properties of the returned object and passes them to component as props.

Thanks to that, in the following line https://github.com/rovercode/rovercode-ui/blob/alpha/src/components/Workspace.js#L293 we could manage to extract `updateJsCode` from the props

So, good news and bad news. In order to explain this to you, I need to spend some time to build a fundamental understanding of what is props, what is higher order components, what is redux, what is actions etc. etc. Once you learn the fundamentals first, it is easier to connect the dots.

2) So in order to answer this question, I need to go through the codebase to understand the architecture of the project. The important thing to be aware of is that, even though there are some certain best practices, every project has its own data structure and architecture. It is up to the creator of the projects to make a decision in terms of component architecture, data structure etc. etc. When you are new and try to understand the technology by checking existing projects, you might end up confusing yourself big time and treating the architecture of those project as source of truths.

My humble suggestion to you is, first things first, try to focus on React without Redux. Because most of the time, you might not even need a state management depending on the scope of the project (again a decision needs to be made by the team etc.)

The things that you might want to learn with React are
1) Parent-child-sibling component relationships
2) React Hook api (relatively new, but usage is increasing dramatically so as a new learner you should definitely take a look)
3) If you want to understand some "old" project and tutorials you might also want to learn about life cycle methods
4) What is presentational component vs container component
5) Higher order components

Once you are comfortable with the fundamental of React, you can then continue with Redux. I bet things will be way more easier

If you need more suggestions, send me a message so I can try to provide you some resources

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I still have a question as next answer (because the length of comment is limited.)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers. After reading your reply and learning related conceptsI, still have a question. You explain that `connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Workspace))` connects component directly to the redux store and use the example to illustrate that `mapDispatchToProps` connects actions to component. So my understanding is `mapStateToProps` connects `state` of redux store to component. e.g., [code](https://github.com/rovercode/rovercode-ui/blob/31109f0a1293caa2b2f0c31af39ff26511382d7b/src/components/Workspace.js#L313) `code` property of `this.props` comes from the `state` of redux store, returned by reducer. Is it right?